# Create conditional submit using jQuery event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Before submitting my form, I wan't to check if inserted dates are available. I have a php script which can perform this check and I want to call this php script via jquery/ajax.

I believe I should use `event.preventDefault();` to avoid that the form is submitted. However I somehow cannot combine it with the Ajax call. The action of the form is performed anyway, the user is redirected to test.html.

What am I doing wrong? Anyone any suggestions?

My .html

```
<form id="checkData" action="test.html" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
<input type="submit" value="Book">
```

My .js

```
 $( "#checkData" ).submit(function( event ) {
   var data = $("#checkData :input").serializeArray();
   $.post("check.php", data, function(json){
    if (json.status == "fail") { //this works fine without using the "event.preventDefault() statement"
      event.preventDefault();
    }
   }, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the preventDefault() on the click event of the submit button instead.

I didn't test the code so it might have some typo.

```
$( "#checkData input[type='submit']" ).click(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var data = $("#checkData :input").serializeArray();
   $.post("check.php", data, function(json){
    if (json.status != "fail") { 
       $(#checkData).submit();
    }
   }, "json");
   event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: I have no reputation, so cannot pay it forward. Therefor: It works, thank you so much Juan.

Comment: No problem, but just check if you can apply the green "tick" to mark this as the answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

- You can prevent the default behavior immediatelly.
- Execute the post request.
- If everything is ok, off the event submit and execute that the form submission programmatically.

```
if (json.status !== "fail") {
    $self.off('submit', fn);
    $self.submit();
}
```

**This is the approach:**

```
function fn(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var data = $("#checkData :input").serializeArray();
  var $self = $(this);
  $.post("check.php", data, function(json) {
    if (json.status !== "fail") {
      $self.off('submit', fn);
      $self.submit();
    }
  }, "json");
}

$("#checkData").submit(fn);
```

Comment: I have no reputation, so cannot pay it forward. Therefor: It works, thank you so much Ele.

Comment: @wieteke Wait a little ~10mins and then you will be able to accept this answer :-)